# How to get top x records in a one to many relation SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Consider the following tables

Book

```
[Id], [Name],     [DatePublished]
1      Test One,  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
2      Test Two   2019-01-02 00:00:00.000
3      Test Three 2019-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Tag

```
[Id], [Name]
1     TagOne
2     TagTwo
3     TagThree
```

BookTag

```
[BookId], [TagId]
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         2
3         3
```

I would like to select with sample above top two books and all of their associated tags and you can order them in whatever way you feel like, that part won't matter.

Here is what I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 AS SplitOn,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Id] ASC)) AS RowNumber, COUNT(*) over() as TotalRows
    FROM (
        SELECT B.[Id], B.[Name], B.[DatePublished], T.[Id] AS TagId, T.[Name] AS TagName
        FROM [Book] B
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [BookTag] BT ON BT.[BookId] = B.[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Tag] T ON T.[Id] = BT.[TagId]
    )
)
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Now the problem with the above query is that it will give each row a unique row number and thus I will always only get first 2 rows. What I really want to get is every row for first 2 book ids. I can't quite figure out how to do that with partitions. Is this possible using Row_Number or do I have to do something completely different?

EDIT: I would like to accomplish this with row_number and partition if it is possible. Reasons are difficult to explain without revealing some sensitive information. Best I can describe it as is that using sub-queries would not make a lot of sense as the example I gave above is very simplified to actual scenario. Actual scenario has much more complex queries.

Expected Result Sample One (Sort by Id ASC):

```
[Id], [Name],   [DatePublished],        [TagId], [TagName], [SplitOn], [RowNumber]. [TotalRows]
1     Test One  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 1        TagOne     1          1            3
1     Test One  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 2        TagTwo     1          1            3
1     Test One  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 3        TagThree   1          1            3
2     Test Two  2019-01-02 00:00:00.000 1        TagOne     1          2            3
3     Test Two  2019-01-02 00:00:00.000 2        TagTwo     1          2            3
```

Expected Result Sample Two (Sort by Date DESC):

```
[Id], [Name],     [DatePublished],        [TagId], [TagName], [SplitOn], [RowNumber]. [TotalRows]
3     Test Three  2019-01-02 00:00:00.000 3        TagThree     1          1            3
2     Test Two    2019-01-02 00:00:00.000 1        TagOne       1          2            3
2     Test Two    2019-01-02 00:00:00.000 2        TagTwo       1          2            3
```

Comment: How do you define "top two books"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you can sort them any way you want as it doesn't matter. By top two i mean using ids of the book.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @GenWan Updated Question

Comment: @Bojan Why is book id 3's name Test Two?

Comment: @GenWan typo, i fixed all the typos.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense what you want. Why do you get a different number of rows returned based on how you sort the data??

Comment: in your first sample, the row 5 should be id 2. BTW, what is SplitOn and total rows? your first sample have 5 rows.

Comment: How do you expect to get 2 for SplitOn? You have it hard coded to 1.

Comment: @SeanLange i'm not sure why that was 2

Answer (score 1):

In this case `ROW_NUMBER()` wouldn't help.
Use `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
select s.id, s.name, s.tag 
from (
  select b.*, t.name tag,
    dense_rank() over (order by b.id) rn
  from book b
  left join booktag bt on bt.bookid = b.id
  left join tag t on t.id = bt.tagid
) s 
where rn <= 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac215e335668937eeb08a7b43d0e7997).
Results:

```
> id | name     | tag     
> -: | :------- | :-------
>  1 | Test One | TagOne  
>  1 | Test One | TagTwo  
>  1 | Test One | TagThree
>  2 | Test Two | TagOne  
>  2 | Test Two | TagTwo
```

Replace:

```
dense_rank() over (order by b.id) rn
```

with:

```
dense_rank() over (order by b.id desc) rn
```

to get the results in descending order of the ids.
Results:

```
> id | name      | tag     
> -: | :-------- | :-------
>  3 | Test Four | TagThree
>  2 | Test Two  | TagOne  
>  2 | Test Two  | TagTwo
```

Comment: DENSE_RANK seems to be doing the trick, however I am trying to understand it fully. How does it know which column to use as in your example (and the one i tested privately) its never specified?

Comment: `dense_rank() over (order by b.id)` sorts the rows by `b.id` and assigns the same number to all equal ids and increments that number for the next id.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading that and there is still one thing I'm failing to understand. Lets say Book one and Book Two have identical Publish Date and you order by PublishDate DESC. Would they both have the same rank or would it be different because they don't have same ids? If different, how does it know to use the id column?

Comment: If you use `dense_rank() over (order by b.PublishDate desc)` then the ids are not involved at all. All books with the same PublishDate will get the same number.

Comment: Then this may not be able to help me the way I need it. I need densing to happen on id always but the order via a different column. Maybe i need to expand the question then.

Comment: *I need densing to happen on id always but the order via a different column* what does this even mean?

Comment: Each rank should be assigned based on the id, not based on the date. The ordering though should happen based on the date. I updated question to include dates.

Comment: The only difference I see is a new column that you can include also in the query and add at the end an `ORDER BY` clause with the sorting that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first two books by id, use a subquery like this:

```
select b.*, t.name
from (select top (2) b.*
      from books b
      order by id
     ) b left join
     booktags bt
     on bt.book_id = b.id left join
     tags t
     on bt.tag_id = t.id;
```

This uses `left join` to support books with no tags.

Comment: I edited the question, please have a look as I'm hoping to find an answer using row_number and partition

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP(2)
       B.id AS BookID, 
       B.name AS BookName,
       STRING_AGG(BT.tagid,', ') AS TagID,
       STRING_AGG(T.id, ', ') AS TagID,
       STRING_AGG(T.name, ', ') AS TagName
FROM dbo.book AS B
LEFT JOIN dbo.booktag AS BT ON BT.bookid = B.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.tag AS T ON B.id = BT.tagid
GROUP BY b.id, b.name
ORDER BY B.id
```

Comment: It is sql server 2014. string_agg is not supported